# How can I set json serializer options per Controller basis (not globally in startup)?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

**Context**

I would like to return with JSON in my ASP.NET Core controller, and use custom `JsonSerializerOptions` and not the globally set in `Startup`

My controller inherits from `ControllerBase`, so there is no `Json(...)` method where I would have chance to pass a custom `JsonSerializerOptions`. (Missing I something?)
Not a problem there are the `Ok(...)` and etc helpers. However those do not support the custom options as passed parameters.

**Question**

As a workaround I can create manually a `JsonResult` and serialize the data into it and also set http status, but is this the simplest way?

(The question and answer is not related if one is using `Newtonsoft` or `System.Text.Json` just sharing I intend to use `System.Text.Json`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JsonSerializer` class to serialize your json with the settings you want and then return it via `Ok(serializedJson)`

```
var serializedData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dataNeedToBeSerialized, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IgnoreNullValues = true
});

return Ok(serializedData);
```

Other way you can create new base controller class which will have Json helpers in it, and then you can call them from your controllers

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase {
    protected internal JsonResult Json(object data)
    {
        return Json(data, null /* contentType */, null /* contentEncoding */, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }

    protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType)
    {
        return Json(data, contentType, null /* contentEncoding */, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }

    protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return Json(data, contentType, contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }

    protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return Json(data, null /* contentType */, null /* contentEncoding */, behavior);
    }

    protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return Json(data, contentType, null /* contentEncoding */, behavior);
    }

    protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In your solution you are serializing a string, which has actually json content. This is not the same, as serializing the original object, for example the quotation marks will be escaped

Comment: I didn't have problems with escapes with this version, anyway you can use the second approach and use the original Json() helper.